# How do I match data in Excel with an Access database?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm using Excel and Access 365 for the record.

I have information on around 100,000 account numbers, far too many for Excel to handle efficiently. I put them into Access.

In Excel, I have a list of about 10 account numbers. This list changes daily. How do I get the account information from Access into Excel? If I was able to keep everything in Excel I would use INDEX MATCH, what is the equivalent to get information from Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably require VBA to do efficiently.

Loop through the account numbers, and for each account number query the Access database (using ADO) and return only the required data for each account.

Comment: I was unaware that I could use VBA between Excel and Access. I will do that, thank you.

Comment: @user9544908 Note that you aren't limited to running VBA under an Excel host; you can use any Automation supporting language -- for example C#, Python, JScript, VBScript -- to both connect to the Access database using ADO (or ADO.NET, for .NET languages), and manipulating the Excel workbook via the Excel object model.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest setting up a linked table to Excel within Access, and running an SQL statement. Much simpler than loops in VBA.

1. Open Access
2. Create a linked table to the Excel worksheet, which is nothing more than connection information to the worksheet; it doesn't actually store the records from the worksheet.

This allows the following:

- **From within Access** -- run queries that join data between Access tables and the linked Excel table. You can save such queries, use them as `RecordSource` for a form or report etc.
- **From within Excel** -- you can open an ADO connection from within Excel and run an SQL statement joining Access tables and the linked Excel worksheet. You can then use the Excel `Range.CopyFromRecordset` method to paste those results into an Excel worksheet.

Comment: How can I do that without bringing all 100,000 rows into Excel?

Stated another way, how do I change my query based on cell data?

Comment: @user9544908 Updated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use the 'In' clause.  I have the following data points on Sheet2 in Range A1:A5.

```
Ryan
Sam
Timmy
Tommy
Teddy
```

Paste the code below into a Module and set a reference to 'Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.8 Library' under Tools in the VBE Window.

```
Sub Import()

 Dim connect As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rec1 As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim wb As Worksheet
 Dim Wb2 As Worksheet
 Dim Param() As ADODB.Parameter
 Dim Command1 As ADODB.Command
 Dim lrow As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim ConcatSQL As String


 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set Wb2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
 lrow = Wb2.Range("A" & Wb2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 'Concatenate desired range into one cell
 For i = 0 To lrow
 ConcatSQL = ConcatSQL & "'" & Wb2.Cells(i + 1, 1) & "'" & ","
 Next i
 ConcatSQL = "(" & Left(ConcatSQL, Len(ConcatSQL) - 1) & ")"

 'Open Command Object with One Paramter
 Set Command1 = New ADODB.Command

 With Command1
    .CommandText = " Select ID, Price from TABLE where ID IN " & ConcatSQL
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandTimeout = 600
 End With


 'Connect to Data Source
  Set connect = GetNewConnection 'Represents Private Function with Connection String
  Command1.ActiveConnection = connect

  Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset
  Set rec1 = Command1.Execute()

  'Paste Results
  wb.Activate

 With wb.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rec1, Destination:=wb.Range("A1"))
 .Name = "data"
 .FieldNames = True
 .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

 'Close Connections
 rec1.Close
 connect.Close
 Set rec1 = Nothing
 Set connect = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Here is a screen shot to show how the variables are created.

[image]

I'm 100% certain that you can run a simple query in Access and export the results of said query to Excel.  Or, save that query, and import the records in the object to Excel.  When you get into larger data sets like you described, you may want to consider using different tools for the job.  Python and R come to mind.